# finding positive roots for a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, root-systems

I have a polynomial, and I want to get the conditions for the number of positive roots
What are the different methods out there to determine these conditions?

this is the polynomial:

f(g)=A1*g^5 + A2*g^4 + A3*g^3 + A4*g^2 + A5*g + A6
and A1 to A6 are constants
I will appreciate any help
Warm regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Abel-Ruffini Theorem postulates the existence of polynomials of every degree above $4$ that are not solvable by radicals (see also Galois' results on the same topic at the beginning of the XIX century, about the necessary and sufficient condition to let a polynomial equation be solvable by radicals).

A good (simple to be read) online source is "Galois Theory: Polynomials of Degree 5 and Up" by Tokuei Higashino.

P.S. Without solving $f(g)=0$, you can use Descartes' Rule of Signs, stating that *the possible number of the positive roots of a polynomial is equal to the number of sign changes in the coefficients of the terms **or** less than the sign changes by a multiple of $2$*.

Comment: Just to clarify my answer: since the user asked about the conditions concerning a $5$-degree polynomial, it has been proved $200$ years ago that we cannot find any general formula solving them all. About the number of positive roots, I can only suggest to take a look at Descartes' rule of signs. Anyway, I'm going to add this info to my previous answer (above).

Comment: thank you for answering, I am facing the problem of getting the positive root numbers of that polynomial because the constants A1to A6 consist of combinations of parameters and I can't know the sign of each term. Is there any way you could help me solve it analytically?